# Doesn't yet exist or doesn't exist yet

Tags: adverb-placement

1. doesn't **yet** exist
2. doesn't exist **yet**

As far as I know `yet` should come at the end of a sentence. Is this a grammar error?

Comment: In formal English, you usually put "yet' immediately after not, but  in conversation and less formal writing, you normally put it at the end of a clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, "yet" goes at the end of a sentence or clause. But It is not a must that *"yet"* should come at the end of the sentence. For example,

> - I have not **ye**t finished.
> - I have **yet** to finish the report.
> - It's freezing cold out, **yet** you still go outside without a jacket.

Here are some examples of sentences with *"yet"* at the end:

> - It is 10 past 12, but they hadn’t arrived **yet**.
>
>   - Are we there **yet**?
> - I haven't been there **yet.**

But in your example, *"yet"* should be ideally used at the end.

> That kind of technology **doesn't exist yet**.

Do visit this link on the use of [*'yet'*](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/yet). It shows many examples that uses *"yet"* in various positions in a sentence.

Comment: How about sentences like this: `"That kind of technology doesn't [yet] exist [yet] in the world [yet]"`. Should 'yet' come at the end too? Are the other two options correct?

Answer (score 5):

**Yet** is normally placed at the end of the clause, particularly **in informal English** and **in questions**, but can go immediately after not in negative sentences in **a more formal style**

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. As you might locate an adverb wherever you want, I think nothing matters. I'm not a native English speaker, sorry for weak answer. I hope you will find answer, soon!